# Run grep in build step in teamcity linux agent

Tags: linux, teamcity

I'm running my teamcity agent in linux. The first step of the build will get the version of a package using a command line script, which contains the following:

`$versionNumber = grep "<Version>" %env.RelativeProjectPath% | sed -e "s/<[^>]*>//g"`

The problem is that I receive this error:

> /BuildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script5887915083946808286: line 1: versionNumber =: command not found

Any ideas why this happens or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using this:

`versionNumber=$(grep '<Version>' %env.RelativeProjectPath% | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g')`